# Given a data set, how to do the following

Tags: data, permutation, data-structures

Please help in executing the following problem in Mathematica:

I have the following set:$A=\{1, 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10\}$ (my actual data has more than 10 points). I need to do the following three steps:

(A) Form all possible pairs of two digits in the above set, like $(1,2), (4,6)$ etc. Remember $(1,2)$ and $(2,1)$ are to be treated as different pairs. Since my actual data is big, I want Mathematica to find all these possible pairs.

(B) Then I have to put these pairs in the following expression: $\eta(x_1,x_2)= x_1+5x_2+10$ and compute the value of $\eta(x_1,x_2)$, for the pair $(x_1,x_2)$.

(C) Similarly, I have to this for all pairs and arrange the values of $\eta(x_1,x_2)$ is decreasing order.

Comment: Look at `Tuples`   eg `Tuples[Range@10, 2]` and `eta@@@Tuples[Range@10, 2]`

Comment: What is the size of data?

Comment: My actual data contains around 100 points.

Comment: If you don't want (1,1) then use `Permutations[Range@10, {2}]`

Comment: Thank you, friends. I would appreciate if you put a slightly detailed answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
f[x1_, x2_] := x1 + 5 x2 + 10
SeedRandom@2;
data = RandomReal[10, 100];
pair = Permutations[data, {2}];
values=Sort[f @@@ pair];
ListPlot[values]
```

Comment: Never knew mathematica had permutation function. Neat answer!

Comment: Thanks. It says "Introduced in 1988 (1.0) | Updated in 2007 (6.0)"